# I can't get exception message when I have http code 401

Tags: java, rest, api, exception, unauthorized

I have two API that comunicate with each other. So API "A" send to API "B" a user and password to authenticated, and if successful returns JWT token.
And when authentication is failure, the API "B" must send the reason of failure to API "A".

But API "A" don't receive the exception message. When I receive HttpClientErrorException, I receive that: "401 null"

```java
// Method in API "B" responsable to authenticated
private User authenticated(UserExternal userInfo, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    try {
        //code for athenticated
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new InvalidLoginException(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

// Class of exception
@ResponseStatus(code=HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
public class InvalidLoginException extends RuntimeException {

    public InvalidLoginException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }

}

// Method responsable to send a request from API "A" to API "B"
protected Object send(HttpMethod method, String path, Object param, Class clazz) {
    RestTemplate rest = getRestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders header = createHeader();
    try {
        HttpEntity<?> requestEntity;
        String url = getURL() + path;
        if (method.equals(HttpMethod.GET)) {
            requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(header);
            UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url);
            builder.queryParams((MultiValueMap<String, String>) param);
            url = decode(builder.toUriString());
        } else {
            requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(param, header);
        }
        ResponseEntity<Object> response = rest.exchange(url, method, requestEntity, clazz);
        return response.getBody();
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(e.getStatusCode(), e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I'm trying get the message error send by API "B". For exemple, if I try authenticated with wrong user, I have to send a exception with the follow message: "Bad credentials" and API "A" get that message and do something with that.

Thank you in advance